# QtWidgets documentation doesn't show up in Qt Creator

Tags: qt-creator

Something happened to Qt Creator and none of the documentations for QtWidgets now appears in the documentation index (or in any other place that I can access it). How can I bring those docs back?

For instance there is no documentation for QLineEdit:

[image]

This is the case whether or not I have a filter set:

[image]

In Preferences, `qtwidgets` is selected.

[image]

I upgraded to Qt Creator 10.0.1, but that didn't make a difference.